# is there an array bitshift operator in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, bit-shift

Is there? for example:

```
unsigned long long myarray[4];
myarray <<= (8*sizeof(unsigned long long));
myarray[3] = my_new_value_at_front;
```

would be equivalent to:

```
unsigned long long myarray[4];
myarray[0] = myarray[1]; 
myarray[1] = myarray[2]; 
myarray[2] = myarray[3]; 
myarray[3] = 0;
myarray[3] = my_new_value_at_front;
```

if not are there any containers which support a constant `N` elements and when you push a new one at `[N-1]` then everithing will be shifted?

Comment: Those are C arrays. If you were using a C++ container class you'd have more luck.

Comment: No. And this isn't a "bitshift", it would be an array shift.

Comment: No, there isn't such. The closest thing you may get is [`std::bitset::operator<<()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_ltltgtgt)

Comment: How about [`std::vector::insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/)?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ would that work with a `union { std::bitset<4*8*sizeof(unsigned long long)>; unsigned long long[4]; };` ?

Comment: @Gizmo _"would that work with a union ..."_ no.

Comment: @tadman I can use std::array that's no problem

Comment: "containers which support a constant N elements and when you push a new one at [N-1] then everithing will be shifted?" -- that exists, it is called a ring buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no operator but you can do:

```
std::rotate(myarray, myarray + N, myarray + 4);
```

where `N` is the index of the element that should be moved to the start, and the other arguments are the begin and end. You could overwrite later elements afterwards if you wanted.

In your case:

```
std::rotate(myarray, myarray + 1, myarray + 4);
myarray[3] = my_new_value_at_front;
```

Comment: Perhaps your answer is better than mine since it is container agnostic.

Comment: @NickyC depends on circumstances I guess; mine will unnecessarily move some objects if all he is going to do is overwrite them

Answer (score 4):

No. There is not. But I can recommend something better. Try `std::deque`.

```
std::deque<unsigned long long> mydeque {0, 1, 2, 3};

for (const auto& x : mydeque )
    std::cout << x << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;

mydeque.pop_front();
mydeque.push_back(4);

for (const auto& x : mydeque )
    std::cout << x << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

With `std::deque`, you can use memeber function `pop_front` to remove the first element, and `push_back` to insert at the back.

Comment: deque doesn't have random access does it?

Comment: @BenVoigt `std::deque` is random access. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with naked arrays but considering you are using an integral type you can use [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) which includes [shift](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/shift) and [circular shift](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/cshift) functions that should meet your requirements. It provides [random access](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/operator_at) much like a naked array but with additional functionality thrown in.